# Contar palabras de un determinado tamaño en C

Tags: c, archivo

Necesito implementar una función que cuente las palabras de un archivo texto.txt que tengo creado, según el tamaño que ingreso mediante argumentos con opciones usando getopt y al momento de ingresar esto:

./ejecutable-c 5 -f texto.txt

Mi programa imprima esto:
"La cantidad de palabras de tamaño >= *5* del archivo *texto.txt* is 10.",

Estoy usando la consola de Linux, hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código el cual no está retornando nada:

```
int count_words(char *filename, int size){
    FILE *f;
   
    scanf("%s", filename);
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(f == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: El archivo '%s' no existe", filename);
        return -1;
    char c;
    while(!feof(f)){
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n'){
            if(strlen(filename) >= size){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Supongo que está corriendo el lazo pero no obtengo mensajes de error para saber qué está mal.

Comment: Este no es un programa completo, no hay una función "main", pero puedo ver varios problemas. `scanf("%s", filename);` --- no, debes obtener esto desde la línea de comando, no leer desde la entrada estándar. `while(!feof(f))` --- esta condición de bucle *siempre* es incorrecta. `char c` --- esto nunca se asigna, pero se verifica más tarde en `if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')`. `strlen(filename)` --- ¿¿¿??? *no obtengo mensajes de error* --- ¿cómo compilas el programa?

Comment: El programa, tras compilarlo, no va a hacer nada. Intentará abrir un fichero, y más tarde, se abra o no, se terminará la ejecución del programa. Recuerda que en un `if`, si se cumple la condición indicada se ejecuta solo la siguiente instrucción (una sola instrucción), o bloque de instrucciones (solo un bloque de instrucciones entre llaves). Por tanto, te falta añadir llaves tras el `if (f == NULL)` que englobe tanto el `printf` como el `return -1`. Aparte de lo que ha comentado @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tomé en cuenta sus observaciones y ya lo pude corregir.